# Achieve Layout Elegantly Without Many Nested Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am attempting to create this layout in AXML:

[image]

However I am unsure of the easiest way to create this and avoid many nested Layout's. I am thinking to have an outer `LinearLayout` (horiz) with 2 `RelativeLayouts` for each column (then add the widgets in there).

So like this:

[image]

But with this current layout its not positioning correctly:

[image]

Can you suggest the easiest way to achieve this layout (ie, not involving many nested layouts) and why my code below isn't displaying correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px"
  android:background="#161615">
 <!-- Listing Details Section -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <RelativeLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.5">
          <Mvx.MvxImageView
              android:id="@+id/listingIcon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              local:MvxBind="ImageUrl LlistingIcon"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/name"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:text="First name Last name"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listingIcon" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/datePosted"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:text="2 days ago"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listingIcon" />
      </RelativeLayout>
      <RelativeLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="0.5">
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/likes"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:text="13 likes"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/comments"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:text="4 comments"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
          <Mvx.MvxImageView
              android:id="@+id/moreInfo"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              local:MvxBind="ImageUrl MoreInfoIcon"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
      </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a single relative layout for it? It seems to me like that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with the below layout (using a single `RelativeLayout`). You may need to adjust padding/margin to your needs to get exactly what you want. I haven't tested it but this should get you close.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
          android:id="@+id/listingIcon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="use appropriate margin for your needs/>
   <TextView
          android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="First name Last name"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listingIcon" />
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/datePosted"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="2 days ago"
          android:layout_below="@+id/name" /> <!-- see this change -->
   <Mvx.MvxImageView
          android:id="@+id/moreInfo"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          local:MvxBind="ImageUrl MoreInfoIcon"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/likes"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="13 likes"
          android:layout_alignPToLeftOf="@id/moreInfo" /> <!-- changed -->
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/comments"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:text="4 comments"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moreInfo"
          android:layout_below="@id/likes" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this with a single horizontal `LinearLayout` and three children.

Your first child would be a `TextView` with a compound drawable.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_icon"
    />
```

The text can be either hardcoded or something you set dynamically, but you can use the [power of Android's spans](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/) if you need different sections of the text to be styled differently. This way you avoid creating unnecessary `TextView`s.

Your second child would be another `TextView`, again with spans if you need to style content differently, and your third child an `ImageButton`.

This approach will require at most two layout passes to succeed. (One if you don't use weights. It may even still be one pass if you specify weight for only one child and give it a width of `0dp`, but I can't quite remember).

A single relative layout could also give you what you want, but requires the definition of confusing constraints and requires two measure/layout passes.